# Lightning component Attribute value is not set in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-apps, internet-explorer, issue

Found this issue in Internet Explorer. Below is my code.

**testApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="opp" type="Opportunity" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Opportunity', 'Name':''}" access="public"/>
    <ui:inputText value="{!v.opp.Name}" keyup="{!c.readName}"/>
</aura:application>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
    readName: function(component, event, helper) {

        if ((event.getParams().keyCode) != 13)
            return;

        var opp = component.get('v.opp');

        console.log('item: '+JSON.stringify(opp));
    },
})
```

- In Internet Explorer

  console.log() logs nothing for **opp.Name**

[image]

- In Firefox (Other browsers also works fine)

[image]

I tried using a String type, but doesn't seem to work for even simple String variables.

Appreciate any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try having a handler on the opp object changing that fires off an action to print to console.

Comment: Hi @Aequitas, Thanks for the comment, but we cannot use the handler since we capture pressed key character (e.g. needs some processing done if ENTER key is pressed).

Comment: A handler can fire actions when keys are pressed as well, you just need to update the value that it's looking at. In your case you would have `updateOn="keyup"` on your ui inputText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning uses the "change" event to determine when to update changes to the data model. Firefox, Chrome, and Edge all fire this event when the contents of an input have changed, but IE 11 only fires this event on a "blur" event if the contents have been changed. That means that IE 11 has different behavior, and if you want Aura to work properly in IE 11, you have to do things differently.

This quirk is one of the primary reasons why you should always have a button for the user to click, instead of supporting Return/Enter, because that introduces the required blur event for the data model to update. However, if you really want to support IE 11 users, you can do so by forcibly blurring the element manually before trying to get the data:

```
({
    readName: function(component, event, helper) {
        if(event.getParams().keyCode === 13) {
            var el = event.getSource() && event.getSource().getElement && 
                event.getSource().getElement();
            el && el.blur && el.blur();
            var opp = component.get('v.opp');
            console.log('item: '+JSON.stringify(opp));
            el && el.focus && el.focus();
        }
    },
})
```

Note that, for some reason, event.getSource().getElement() doesn't seem to work in Firefox, Chrome, or Edge, so we have to guard against that as well. You'll need to do this every time you need the updated data model on a keypress in IE 11. This is just one of the many little quirks you'll enjoy as an IE 11 developer. IE 11 is not particularly standards compliant, so whenever you run in to issues like this, you'll need to remember that IE 11 needs to be treated special, which is why Salesforce doesn't even support IE 11 for LEX.

Comment: Many Thanks for the explanation @sfdcfox, that works well.